# Rendering fading in text object problem

Tags: rendering, transparency

I'm trying to make an intro video and stumbled upon the following problem.
Ì have 4 text objects parented to a box.
The box provides the moving animation and this works without fail.

The text objects all use the same material.
On frame 1 and 100 I set a keyframe on the materials transparency (alpha0)
On frame 115 I set another keyframe for the materials transparency (alpha100)
However, this only works when I have the text opbjects selected, And only in the 3d view.

Instead when the fade in starts, the text objects turn black and fade to their materials color.

Any help on this?

[image]

Comment: The problem can have mutliple sources, if you could upload your blend file to http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/, it would be much easier to find the problem

Comment: Added the blend file. Thanks for the comment, didn't know I could do that. In the blend file all the text objects have their own material, failed attempt at a fix.

Comment: As long as the background is black it works as intended

Comment: Turned ON xray under ObjectProperties.
Problem Solved